# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'fontFamily' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have an assignment in javascript that changes the font of the  tag on button click but I'm getting this error. I don't think there is anything wrong in my code.

```
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Set font</button>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementsByTagName("body").style.fontFamily = "Times New Roman, Times, serif";
    }
```

Comment: You can directly use `document.body`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName("body")` does not return a single element, but an array of items.

You can fix your code by accessing the array by index:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.fontFamily
```

Edit: On a side note as Ivar has mentioned in his comment: the body can be accessed explicitly with `document.body`.